# GWT+GAE error :failed org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector by running GWTTestCase-JUnit

Tags: gwt, gae-eclipse-plugin

I usually use Eclipse IDE for GAE+GWT project.

Environment:GWT2.1.1, GAE 1.4.0

In GWT Project(without GAE), using GWTTestCase in the project,,,
→no problem. run well.

In GWT+GAE Project, using GWTTestCase in the project for GWT,,,
→When running the test that extends GWTTestcase,
error comes.

Error is below:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mortbay.thread.Timeout.(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.(SelectorManager.java:306)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:223)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:303)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:233)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:542)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:431)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1053)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.getUnitTestShell(JUnitShell.java:680)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:625)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:456)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:311)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Sources of test are below:
    package com.companyName.client;

```
import com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase;

public class Test extends GWTTestCase {


@Override
public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.companyName.projectName";
}


/**
 * test
 */
public void testNumburOne () {
    System.out.println("testNumburOne");
}

}
```

without GAE, that will run normally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to remove the package. Just make sure that the GWT jar is refererenced ahead of the appengine jar in the build path.

Comment: Why didn't I just come to StackOverflow and read this a few hours ago? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's it. So easy ... and I've already re-installed Eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late reply, but I only just had this issue myself.

You have a ClassPath conflict.

The org.mortbay packages are included in both the GWT and Appengine libraries.

I just removed them from my copy of the Appengine library - so that they are still available from the GWT library. Everything now seems to be OK.

BestRegards

Geoff Bruckner

Comment: Thank you! easy to understand. I'll try it.